# dynamically adding textviews to listview item

Tags: android-layout, listview, android-listview

I have this arryalist of items, each item has hour as string and string of minutes. I can split minutes to array and for each minute I want to add textview with on clicklistener.

I have implemented arrayadapter for listview. Everything works like expected but only one thing : I don't see all textviews as they are not shown properly on the end of the display.

ListView row item layout has LinearLayout and textview to show hours.

Code for listview adapter :

```
public class DotazAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Hours> {

    private final ArrayList<Hours> model;
    private final Context context;

    public DotazAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Hours> model) {
        super(context, R.layout.hours_minutes,model);
        this.model=model;
        this.context=context;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = null;
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hours_minutes, parent,false);
        LinearLayout riadok = (LinearLayout)row.findViewById(R.id.horny);

        TextView hodiny = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.hodinyBTV);
        hodiny.setText(model.get(position).getHour());

        String[] minuty = model.get(position).getMinutes().split(" ");

        for(int i = 0; i<minuty.length;i++){
            final TextView minutka = new TextView(context);

            minutka.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            minutka.setText(minuty[i]+"  ");


            minutka.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Stlacil si riadok "+position+ " a cislo v riadku :", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

            riadok.addView(minutka, );
        }
        return row; 
    }

}
```

Layout for listitem :

```
xml version=1.0 encoding=utf-8
LinearLayout xmlnsandroid=httpschemas.android.comapkresandroid
    androidid=@+idhorny
    androidlayout_width=match_parent
    androidlayout_height=wrap_content

        TextView
            androidid=@+idhodinyBTV
            androidlayout_width=wrap_content
            androidlayout_height=wrap_content
            androidlayout_marginRight=5dp
            androidbackground=#F00C0C
            androidtextColor=#FFFFFF
            androidtextSize=18sp



LinearLayout
```

Comment: You really should read about the ViewHolder Pattern like in section 8 of this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html).

Comment: please dont say that ... I know how to use ViewHolder, but I am not sure if this would work on dynamically added textviews. Number of those textviews is based on minuty.length